# How can I find all the advertisements in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, advertising

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) users know that the site shows advertisements occasionally. I can remember in a  blurred way that perhaps there is a place at the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) site that shows in one place all the advertisements that are displayed on the site.

Where can I find that, i.e. what is the address of that page?

Comment: Do you mean all ads or just the community ads? Example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/community-ads. I don't think there is one such page and if there was why would this be useful to you?

Comment: @rene, I mean ads being displayed in Stack Overflow site ?

Comment: I've been an avid SE user and observer for quite a bit and I've never heard of such a page. SE's also gone through 2-3 different ad serving systems in the time

Comment: Its not clear that stackexchange themselves know all the ads that are shown, given the trouble they have had with inappropriate ads.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such page or list publicly available on Stack Overflow and it is unlikely the company is going to reveal which customers run ads on the platform.

The only community driven  driven list of ads are the so called [Community Ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/community-ads).

Comment: I am not talking about the customers though...

Comment: It is inevitable that listing the ads, list the customers, right?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed even then, some ads are also served based on the user's location. Personally, I haven't seen the problematic ads that have been reported here. But instead, I have seen other ads that are as annoying...